# How to trigger an action using an Ember Service?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I am attempting to use an Ember Service to trigger the same action on multiple routes.

Here is what the service looks like:

```js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Service.extend({
  changeBackground() {
    Ember.$('body').toggleClass('bg-color-change');
  }
});
```

I am then sticking this into the template:

```html
<button id="change-theme" class="btn" {{changeTheme}}>Change Theme</button>
```

And this into the route handler:

```js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
  ...
  changeTheme: Ember.inject.service(),
  ...
});
```

What am I missing here? I suspect the syntax is wrong in some way, I'm just not really sure where to go from here. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all manipulating DOM element inside service function is not advisable.
Regarding your issue,
1. You need to include `action` helper to call function.
2. To make it work for service function call, we need to mention target attribute.
3. Inject changeTheme service in corresponding controller.

```
<button id="change-theme" class="btn" {{action "changeBackground" target=changeTheme}}>Change Theme</button>
```

[Sample Twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/8e9eb7e52f346e9747c2a29f0a6081ba?openFiles=controllers.application.js%2C)

Comment: That worked, thank you! Just out of curiosity, why is manipulating a DOM element inside of a service function not advisable? I'm a student and still have a lot to learn about using Ember.

Comment: It's just my opinion, there is no guarantee that those dom element exist when some one is calling service function. In your case 'body' element will definitely exists. So i guess no problem.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Thanks for clarifying!